# How can I get value from one table and array of values from another join table in one mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called lists and a join table called `items_to_lists`.

I want to query and return all lists for a particular user:

```
SELECT lists.* FROM lists WHERE lists.user_id = 'someUserID'
```

But I also want to include in this query all of the item_id values in the join table as an array for each list.  Is this possible?  What I want to be returned is:

```
list_id = ... , user_id = ... [deck_id1, deck_id2, etc] for each list.
```

What I have tried is:

```
SELECT lists.*, items_to_lists.item_id FROM lists INNER JOIN items_to_lists ON items_to_lists.list_id = lists.list_id WHERE lists.user_id = 'someUserID'
```

This returns each relation as a separate row rather than an array associated with each list.  Is there anyway to return the list row with an array of the join table item_id's?

Comment: You could use `GROUP_CONCAT` with `GROUP BY`, something like this `SELECT lists.list_id, GROUP_CONCAT(items_to_lists.item_id) FROM lists INNER JOIN items_to_lists ON items_to_lists.list_id = lists.list_id WHERE lists.user_id = 'someUserID' GROUP BY lists.list_id`

Comment: that seems to work.  if you put it as an answer I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `GROUP_CONCAT` with `GROUP BY`, something like this:

```
SELECT
  lists.list_id, GROUP_CONCAT(items_to_lists.item_id)
FROM lists INNER JOIN items_to_lists ON items_to_lists.list_id = lists.list_id
WHERE
  lists.user_id = 'someUserID'
GROUP BY
  lists.list_id
```

Comment: just noticed if the list has no items_to_lists.item_id associated it doesn't return anything. I still want the list row for lists that don't have any item_ids associated.  how can I do that?

Comment: use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 2):

[GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) has some more Options like choosing the SEPERAOTR or Ordering the ids

```
SELECT l.*, CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT il.item_id) ,']')
FROM lists l INNER JOIN items_to_lists il ON il.list_id = l.list_id 
WHERE l.user_id = 'someUserID'
```